# Oracle Stored procedures to insert unique id with prefix employee number

Tags: sql, oracle

I have a family declaration table. While employee will declare their family member details, I want to give a unique ID to each family member. if the employee id is 76331 and have 3 family members, then the unique id will be 76331_1,76331_2,76331_3 and the sequence number will be like this for all employees.

The expected output should look like,

```
EmployeeCode             Unique id                 Family member name
---------------------------------------------------------------------
76331                    76331_1                           X    
76331                    76331_2                           Y    
76331                    76331_3                           Z    
71873                    71873_1                           A    
71873                    71873_2                           B
```

Comment: The proper solution is -- don't do that.  By repeating the employee_code as part of another data element, you are unnecessarily repeating data and breaking one of the most fundamental rules of data normalization.   I strongly suspect that your combining the two in a single column is an x-y problem.  If you would explain why you think you need that, we can probably suggest a better approach.

Comment: What happens when you hire a family member?

Answer (score 0):

One option is to use `ROW_NUMBER` analytic function:

```
SQL> with fam (code, name) as
  2    (select 76331, 'X' from dual union all
  3     select 76331, 'Y' from dual union all
  4     select 76331, 'Z' from dual union all
  5     --
  6     select 71873, 'A' from dual union all
  7     select 71873, 'B' from dual
  8    )
  9  select
 10    code,
 11    code ||'_'|| row_number() over (partition by code order by name) unique_id,
 12    name
 13  from fam
 14  order by code, name;

      CODE UNIQUE_ID  NAME
---------- ---------- ----
     71873 71873_1    A
     71873 71873_2    B
     76331 76331_1    X
     76331 76331_2    Y
     76331 76331_3    Z

SQL>
```

Comment: I need store procedure to automatically update the unique_id.

Comment: This is the way *how* to do it. Convert it to a stored procedure.